# Slider Revolution video on autoplay doesn't start

Tags: videos

In my wordpress website I use slider revolution to make slider, on one of my sliders I have a video in autoplay.
With a update of chrone this autoplay doesn't work and to make it work again I put the video on mute, but now I don't know why (maybe another update), this don't work again, and i don't touch anything.

It work on all browser except chrome :/
How can i solve that problem ?
Thanks.

Here is the code of the iframe who show the video :

```
<iframe type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8c7p9__weow?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;html5=1&amp;hd=1&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;mute=1;;origin=https://adncom.fr;&amp;controls=0" width="100%" height="100%" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; width: 100%; height: 118.406%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -9.20313%;" class="resizelistener" id="iframe57619"></iframe>
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I would suggest making an [edit] to include the minimal amount of code for us to be able to help you.  At this moment this is too broad and will likely be closed and see downvotes.  Please take a few minutes to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I don't have many code to add, I use the plugin and not coding. I add the youtube iframe.